# Randomly getting hearts?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I'm getting a half heart randomly - maybe on some sort of timer delay. What could this be? I've looked in the wiki and couldn't see anything.

I have Lil brimstone, ball of bandages, sissy Long legs, lucky poop, and various passive effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are certain itmes that restore your health over time, like [Placenta](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Placenta) (automatically restores health after some time), [Charm of the vampire](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Charm_Of_The_Vampire) (heals after killing enemies)  or  [little C.H.A.D](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Little_C.H.A.D.) (drops half-hears). The trinket [Isaacs Fork](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Isaac%27s_Fork) may also heal you after clearing a room and the [leech](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Leech) familiar heals you when it kills an enemy.

Placenta commonly shows up after a boss fight, charm of the vampire shows up in item rooms and little C.H.A.D shows up when defeating C.H.A.D

Comment: Good old overpowered Placenta.

Comment: FWIW I think it was placenta